# Migrate files from MySQL BLOBs to PostgreSQL largeobjects

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.x, time-limit-exceeded, postgresql

As title says, this piece of code migrates files (binary and metadata) from a database to another one with different structure.

Currently my problem is that when I have to deal with a big database (between 12 and 30GB) , at a certain point the script **CRASHES**. With the 30GB database, this took 4 days of activity and then it just got killed from the system.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# ------------------------------
# Import standard libraries    |
# ------------------------------
#
import os
import sys
import mysql.connector
import psycopg2
import shutil
import base64

# ------------------------------
# Import internal snippets     |
# ------------------------------
#
from include.db_config import *
from include.functions import *

# ------------------------------
# Open database connections    |
# ------------------------------
#
# Mysql connection
try:
    cnx_msql = mysql.connector.connect( host=host_mysql, user=user_mysql, passwd=pswd_mysql, db=dbna_mysql )
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print "MYSQL: Unable to connect!", e.msg
    sys.exit(1)

# Mysql unbuffered connection
try:
    cnx_msql_unbuffered = mysql.connector.connect( host=host_mysql, user=user_mysql, passwd=pswd_mysql, db=dbna_mysql )
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print "MYSQL: Unable to connect!", e.msg
    sys.exit(1)


# Postgresql connection
try:
    cnx_psql = psycopg2.connect(**psql_param)
    # enable autocommit
    #cnx_psql.set_isolation_level(0)
except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print('PSQL: Unable to connect!\n{0}').format(e)
    sys.exit(1)



# -----------
# FUNCTIONS |
# -----------
#
def fv_missing_records():
    cur_msql = cnx_msql_unbuffered.cursor(dictionary=True)
    cur_psql = cnx_psql.cursor()

    qry_1 = "SELECT r.resource_id, r.author_id, r.create_date, r.visible_from, '' AS description, r.size, \
             r.format, r.content_type, r.status, rep.content, rep.iv, 1 as version, NULL AS loid \
             FROM resources r \
             INNER JOIN repository rep ON r.RESOURCE_ID=rep.RESOURCE_ID AND rep.VERSION=1 \
             LEFT JOIN versions v ON r.RESOURCE_ID=v.RESOURCE_ID \
             WHERE v.RESOURCE_ID IS NULL and r.type = 4 ORDER BY r.RESOURCE_ID;"

    execute_msql(cur_msql, qry_1)

    qry_psql = "INSERT INTO file_versions(resource_id, author_id, create_date, publication_date, version, \
             description, size, format, content_type, status, file_oid, iv) VALUES"
    arg_psql = "(%(resource_id)s, %(author_id)s, %(create_date)s, %(visible_from)s, %(version)s, \
             %(description)s, %(size)s, %(format)s, %(content_type)s, %(status)s, %(loid)s, %(iv)s)"

    args_tmp = []
    for row in cur_msql:
        loid=lobject_direct_migration(cnx_psql, row['content']) ##cur_psql seem to be useless here, check it
        # convert iv string to bytearray
        row['iv'] = convert_iv(row['iv'])
        # fix oid for the current row
        row['loid'] = loid

        dataset = cur_psql.mogrify(arg_psql, row)
        execute_psql(cnx_psql, cur_psql, qry_psql, dataset, False)

    info_sleep("Done adding missing records in file_versions!", 3)

    cur_msql.close()
    cur_psql.close()




def migrate_files(function_args):
    #temporarely drop fk constraints
    disable_fks(cnx_psql)

    #here I'm outsite key-values foreach
    fv_missing_records()

    for key, values in function_args.items():
        cur_msql = cnx_msql_unbuffered.cursor(dictionary=True)
        cur_msql1 = cnx_msql.cursor(dictionary=True)
        cur_psql = cnx_psql.cursor()

        # SELECT from source db
        cur_msql.execute(values[0])

        for row in cur_msql:
            #DEBUG#print row

            if key == "files":
                #print row['rid']
                full_qry="SELECT resource_id, path, address, asas_id, progress \
                            FROM resources \
                            WHERE resource_id={0}".format(row['rid'])

                # execute full query
                cur_msql1.execute(full_qry)

                for the_row in cur_msql1:
                    the_row = casting_repository_types(the_row)
                    ### INSERT the row into destination db
                    #print the_row
                    dataset = cur_psql.mogrify(values[2], the_row)
                    #print dataset
                    execute_psql(cnx_psql, cur_psql, values[1], dataset, False)

            elif key == "file_versions":

                full_qry="SELECT v.resource_id, v.version, rep.content, v.description, v.format, v.content_type, \
                    v.size, v.user_id, v.timestamp, v.status, rep.iv, NULL AS loid \
                    FROM versions v \
                    INNER JOIN repository rep \
                    ON v.resource_id = rep.resource_id \
                    AND v.version = rep.version \
                    WHERE v.resource_id={0} AND v.version={1}".format(row['resource_id'], row['version'])

                # execute full query
                cur_msql1.execute(full_qry)

                for the_row in cur_msql1:
                    dataset = cur_psql.mogrify(values[2], the_row)
                    ### INSERT the row into destination db
                    execute_psql(cnx_psql, cur_psql, values[1], dataset, False)

                loid=lobject_direct_migration(cnx_psql, the_row['content'])
                # convert iv string to bytearray
                the_row['iv']=convert_iv(the_row['iv'])
                # fix oid for the current row
                the_row['loid']=loid

            elif key == "file_secview":

                full_qry="SELECT resource_id, page, version, content, iv, NULL AS loid \
                    FROM repository_secview \
                    WHERE resource_id={0} AND page={1} AND version={2}".format(row['resource_id'], row['page'], row['version'])

                # execute full query
                cur_msql1.execute(full_qry)

                for the_row in cur_msql1:
                    dataset = cur_psql.mogrify(values[2], the_row)
                    ### INSERT the row into destination db
                    execute_psql(cnx_psql, cur_psql, values[1], dataset, False)

                loid=lobject_direct_migration(cnx_psql, the_row['content'])
                # fix page, in A3 starting from 0
                the_row['page']=the_row['page']+1
                # convert iv string to bytearray
                the_row['iv']=convert_iv(the_row['iv'])
                # fix oid for the current row
                the_row['loid']=loid

            elif key == "file_secprint":
                full_qry="SELECT resource_id, version, content, iv, NULL AS loid \
                    FROM repository_secprint \
                    WHERE resource_id={0} AND version={1}".format(row['resource_id'], row['version'])

                # execute full query
                cur_msql1.execute(full_qry)

                for the_row in cur_msql1:
                    dataset = cur_psql.mogrify(values[2], the_row)
                    ### INSERT the row into destination db
                    execute_psql(cnx_psql, cur_psql, values[1], dataset, False)

                loid=lobject_direct_migration(cnx_psql, the_row['content'])
                # convert iv string to bytearray
                the_row['iv']=convert_iv(the_row['iv'])
                # fix oid for the current row
                the_row['loid']=loid

            elif key == "annotations":
                full_qry="SELECT a.resource_id, ifnull(MAX(v.version), 1) AS maxversion, a.attachment_number, a.author_id, \
                            a.content, iv, a.update_date, NULL AS loid \
                            FROM annotations a LEFT JOIN versions v ON a.resource_id=v.resource_id \
                            WHERE resource_id={0} GROUP BY a.resource_id".format(row['resource_id'])

                # execute full query
                cur_msql1.execute(full_qry)

                for the_row in cur_msql1:
                    dataset = cur_psql.mogrify(values[2], the_row)
                    ### INSERT the row into destination db
                    execute_psql(cnx_psql, cur_psql, values[1], dataset, False)


                loid=lobject_direct_migration(cnx_psql, the_row['content'])
                # convert iv string to bytearray
                the_row['iv']=convert_iv(the_row['iv'])
                # fix oid for the current row
                the_row['loid']=loid

        # Cursors close
        cur_msql.close()
        cur_psql.close()

    # fix back foreigh keys
    enable_fks(cnx_psql)

    info_sleep("Done with files!", 3)




# --------------
# Conversions  |
# --------------
#
def casting_repository_types(the_row):
    # Data type conversion : smallint to boolean
    if the_row['progress'] == 0:
        the_row['progress'] = False
    elif the_row['progress'] == 1:
        the_row['progress'] = True
    if the_row['path'] == None:
        the_row['path'] = 0
    return the_row




# ------------
# Queries    |
# ------------
#
function_args={ 'files':[], 'file_versions':[], 'file_secview':[], 'file_secprint':[], 'annotations':[]}


files=[
"SELECT resource_id as rid FROM resources \
WHERE type=4 and subtype=2",
"INSERT INTO files (resource_id, reference_id, address, versions_to_kept, show_in_welcome) VALUES ",
"(%(resource_id)s, %(path)s, %(address)s, %(asas_id)s, %(progress)s)"
]

file_versions=[ # /!\ publication_date, approval_request_date & signed_file_version set to NULL
"SELECT v.resource_id, v.version \
FROM versions v \
INNER JOIN repository rep \
ON v.resource_id = rep.resource_id \
AND v.version = rep.version",
"INSERT INTO file_versions (resource_id, author_id, create_date, version, description, size, format, content_type, status, file_oid, iv) VALUES ",
"(%(resource_id)s, %(user_id)s, %(timestamp)s, %(version)s, %(description)s, %(size)s, %(format)s, %(content_type)s, %(status)s, %(loid)s, %(iv)s)"
]

file_secview=[
"SELECT resource_id, page, version FROM repository_secview",
"INSERT INTO file_secview (resource_id, version, page, file_oid, iv) VALUES ",
"(%(resource_id)s, %(version)s, %(page)s, %(loid)s, %(iv)s)"
]

file_secprint=[
"SELECT resource_id, version FROM repository_secprint",
"INSERT INTO file_secprint (resource_id, version, file_oid, iv) VALUES ",
"(%(resource_id)s, %(version)s, %(loid)s, %(iv)s)"
]

annotations=[
"SELECT a.resource_id FROM annotations a LEFT JOIN versions v ON a.resource_id=v.resource_id GROUP BY a.resource_id",
"INSERT INTO annotations (resource_id, version, author_id, file_oid, iv, update_date) VALUES ",
"(%(resource_id)s, %(maxversion)s, %(author_id)s, %(loid)s, %(iv)s, %(update_date)s)"
]


for arg in files:
    function_args['files'].append(arg)

for arg in file_versions:
    function_args['file_versions'].append(arg)

for arg in file_secview:
    function_args['file_secview'].append(arg)

for arg in file_secprint:
    function_args['file_secprint'].append(arg)

for arg in annotations:
    function_args['annotations'].append(arg)

migrate_files(function_args)




############## END OF SCRIPT ################
#-------------------------------------------#
# Finalizing stuff & closing db connections #
#-------------------------------------------#
#############################################

## Committing
cnx_psql.commit()

## Closing database connections
cnx_msql_unbuffered.close()
cnx_msql.close()
cnx_psql.close()
```

Here it is(below) the functions called by the main script(above):

```
### EXECUTE QUERIES ON DBs
def execute_psql(cnx_psql, cursor, query, dataset = None, direct_commit = False):
    if dataset:
        try:
            cursor.execute( query + dataset )
            print "EXECUTED QUERY : " + query + dataset
        except psycopg2.Error as err:
            print "/!\ Cannot execute the query on " + query + dataset, err.pgerror
            cnx_psql.rollback()
            sys.exit( "Rolledback! And leaving early this lucky script, find out what is wrong" )
    else:
        print "The dataset for " + query + " is empty, skipping..."
    return cursor


def execute_msql(cursor, query):
    try:
        cursor.execute( query )
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print "/!\ Cannot execute the following query:" , query
        print "/!\ Error:", err
        sys.exit( "leaving early this lucky script, find out what is wrong" )
    return cursor


### FILES migration
def convert_iv(iv):
    if iv:
        iv = bytearray((base64.b64decode(string)))
    return iv


def lobject_direct_migration(cnx_psql, blob):
    bytearray_to_string = str(bytearray(blob))
    loid = cnx_psql.lobject().oid

    try:
        cnx_psql.lobject(loid, mode='w').write( bytearray_to_string )
        print "lo_migration | new oid : "+str(loid)
        del bytearray_to_string
    except psycopg2.Error as err:
        print "/!\ Cannot insert large_object " + str(loid), err.pgerror
        cnx_psql.rollback()
        sys.exit( "Rollback! And leaving early this lucky script, find out what is wrong" )
    return loid
```

**Logging and monitoring:**
Additionally, in order to check the system resources consuming, I've implemented the following function, and called it after each query, but the system memory usage was very stable, and under a warning limit.

```
def get_log():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    print '\n*** BEGIN LOGGING ***'

    print 'DATETIME: '+str(now)
    print 'MEMORY USAGE: '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss)+' Kilobyte'
    print 'TIME IN USER MODE (FLOAT): '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_utime)
    print 'TIME IN SYSTEM MODE (FLOAT): '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_stime)
    print 'SHARED MEMORY USAGE: '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_ixrss)+' Kilobyte'
    print 'UNSHARED MEMORY USAGE: '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_idrss)+' Kilobyte'
    print 'PAGE FAULTS NOT REQUIRING I/O: '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_minflt)
    print 'PAGE FAULTS REQUIRING I/O: '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_majflt)
    print 'NUMBER OF SWAP OUTS: '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_nswap)
    print 'BLOCK INPUT OPERATIONS: '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_inblock)
    print 'BLOCK OUTPUT OPERATIONS: '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_oublock)
    print 'MESSAGES SENT: '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_msgsnd)
    print 'MESSAGES RECEIVED: '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_msgrcv)
    print 'SIGNALS RECEIVED: '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_nsignals)
    print 'VOLUNTARY CONTEXT SWITCHES: '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_nvcsw)
    print 'INVOLUNTARY CONTEXT SWITCHES: '+str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_nivcsw)

    ## LIMITS ON RESOURCES USAGE
    #print str(resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CORE))
    #print str(resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU))
    #print str(resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_FSIZE))

    print '*** END LOGGING ***\n'
    return True
```

**Trunk of a report**
Following a piece of the report obtained, as you can see, the datetime is unfortunately rounded at the second, but it is clear, to migrate each record less that 1 second is needed, most of the time is spended during the preparation of the record to be migrated

```
2016-06-23 03:41:35 | SOURCE DB QUERY : SELECT resource_id, page, version, content, iv, NULL AS loid                     FROM repository_secview                     WHERE resource_id=1445333482345622 AND page=0 AND version=1
2016-06-23 03:41:35 | DESTINATION DB QUERY : INSERT INTO file_secview (resource_id, version, page, file_oid, iv) VALUES (1445333482345622, 1, 1, 2095944, NULL)
2016-06-23 03:41:38 | SOURCE DB QUERY : SELECT resource_id, page, version, content, iv, NULL AS loid                     FROM repository_secview                     WHERE resource_id=1445333501859624 AND page=0 AND version=1
2016-06-23 03:41:38 | DESTINATION DB QUERY : INSERT INTO file_secview (resource_id, version, page, file_oid, iv) VALUES (1445333501859624, 1, 1, 2095945, NULL)
2016-06-23 03:41:40 | SOURCE DB QUERY : SELECT resource_id, page, version, content, iv, NULL AS loid                     FROM repository_secview                     WHERE resource_id=1457424635012030 AND page=0 AND version=1
2016-06-23 03:41:40 | DESTINATION DB QUERY : INSERT INTO file_secview (resource_id, version, page, file_oid, iv) VALUES (1457424635012030, 1, 1, 2095946, NULL)
```

Does anyone see a bottleneck? In my opinion the issue could lay into the following conversion into string, located into `lobject_direct_migration()` function, but I don't see any other way to perform the same action:

```
bytearray_to_string = str(bytearray(blob))
```

Any way to tune this snippet in order to have better performance? any improvement tip is welcome. I would like to decrease the execution time to 1day maximum : )

Comment: Have you done any performance measuring already?

Comment: You got a `for` in an `if` in a `for` in a `for`. I'm not surprised it takes forever to execute, but you indicate it currently takes over two days for 30GB? That's looong. Good idea to get this reviewed! :-)

Comment: Dear Pimgd, Excuse me if I updated the question with important informations, This post was 18days old, and some progress has been performed in the meaning time, it didn't received enough attention and today I decided to grant the bounty. So I kindly ask to read again the updated question

Comment: @lese good that you checked for performance; what I'm interested in is, how much time do you spend waiting for queries? How much time are you processing results?

Comment: Currently, the real problem, is that the script at a certain point crashes without throwing any error. The performance is not the main pain point of my question, I can accept 3 or 4 days of execution time, since it is one time migration. The real point of the question, is that that with big database, the operation get stuck/crash

Comment: To migrate each record less that 1 second is needed, it seems that, like @Mast suggested, most of the time (around 2 and 3 second) is spended during the preparation of the record to be migrated, so the `for` in an `if` in a `for` in a `for`

Comment: I don't know why you are doing this in Python. Why not do SQL dump and import to bring existing content into Postgres and then transform the data there via whatever queries you need to do? Your desire to transform while moving the data seems fragile. Also, do you really need to store binary data in this manner vs. just references to locations in a file store. You are running into one of the big issues with this approach.

Comment: @MikeBrant smells like an answer

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any performance metrics, so there is no telling whether this will have a significant effect, but one of the things you could do is combine your queries.

Take this one:

```
full_qry="SELECT resource_id, path, address, asas_id, progress \
            FROM resources \
            WHERE resource_id={0}".format(row['rid'])
```

If you first gathered all the `rid`'s, you could then do this:

```
full_qry="SELECT resource_id, path, address, asas_id, progress \
            FROM resources \
            WHERE resource_id IN {0}"
```

That way you go to the database once and allow the database engine to optimize your one query, rather than the lot that you're shooting at it.

You could do the same with other queries, but you'd have to do some more processing to split the resultset back to something you can work with.

```
            full_qry="SELECT v.resource_id, v.version, rep.content, v.description, v.format, v.content_type, \
                v.size, v.user_id, v.timestamp, v.status, rep.iv, NULL AS loid \
                FROM versions v \
                INNER JOIN repository rep \
                ON v.resource_id = rep.resource_id \
                AND v.version = rep.version \
                WHERE v.resource_id={0} AND v.version={1}".format(row['resource_id'], row['version'])
```

This too could be combined, but you'd have to do more work to get a good combination. You know better than I how the original data looks, so if you have a lot of the same version numbers ("rev1", "rev2", "rev3") and wildly varying resource id's, then you'd be better off making it `WHERE v.resource_id IN` with a fixed `v.version`. But if the resource id's are mostly the same and you have a lot of versions, then you might want to put the IN clause for `v.version`.

Whether or not this is worth it can be determined by just printing the queries, then sorting them by type, and running a few non-combined and combined queries by hand.

Comment: Sorry again for have not mentioned this until now. The previous versions of my script, was implemented in order to make a big query from the source database, put everything in a big dictionary, a perform a sigle huge insert like : `insert into table values %s" % [A LIST OF LOTS OF ELEMENTS/RECORDS]`.
As you will certainly understand, this approach would provide much more performance, but from the other side, much more system resources (MEMORY) consuming. I've performed this refactoring, in order to make a select of a record folowed by an insert of a record, in order to avoid the CRASH

Comment: @lese my suggestion is different: 1 query to read the objects into a database resultset (with a cursor, so all the database engine has to do is keep track of an index, rather than give you a several GB resultset), then iterate to insert.